# Spring security fails JdbcClientDetailsService error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently getting this error:

```
 org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
```

Which is handled by the DaoAuthenticationProvider however, it throws an InternalAuthenticationServiceException exception. This bypasses the exception handling of the ProviderManager, which does not call my customDaoProvider which would authenticate the user.

There are 2 DaoAuthenticationProvider registred with the ProviderManager. My observation is that on the first iteration of the ProviderManager, it selects DefaultAuthenticationProvider. I figure that is how it works, which would fail then the ProviderManager, on it's second Iteration would select my custom DaoAuthenticationProvider (customDaoProvider ) to verify the user credential. Thing is on the first iteration, when it fails it throws that specific error that the ProviderManager would rethrow.

This is inside the ProviderManager that would capture the specific error:

```
  try {
            result = provider.authenticate(authentication);

            if (result != null) {
                copyDetails(authentication, result);
                break;
            }
        } catch (AccountStatusException e) {
            prepareException(e, authentication);
            // SEC-546: Avoid polling additional providers if auth failure is due to invalid account status
            throw e;
        } catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException e) {
            prepareException(e, authentication);
            throw e;
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            lastException = e;
        }
```

Note the catch for `InternalAuthenticationServiceException`. Here it rethrow the exception and stop the authentication process.

My entire security.xml below (except the  element):

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"   authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="ROLE_FRONTEND"  />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"  />

    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />

    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


 <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="customDaoProvider">
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>


<beans:bean id="customUserDetailService" class="com.xxxx.api.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="accountService" ref="userAccountServiceImpl"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- DAO Providers -->
<beans:bean id="customDaoProvider" class="com.xxxx.api.daoauthproviders.CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailService"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
    <beans:property name="accountService" ref="userAccountServiceImpl"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="clientService" ref="clientServiceImpl"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<!-- End of DAO Providers  -->

<beans:bean id="clientDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.JdbcClientDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>   

<oauth:authorization-server  client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="customPasswordGrant"/>
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="randomTokenGrant" />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<beans:bean id="restServicesSuccessHandler" class="com.xxxx.api.handlers.RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />   



<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="api" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

<beans:bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="api/" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Custom Grant Types -->
<beans:bean id="randomTokenGrant" class="com.xxxx.api.grants.RandomTokenGrant">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0"><beans:value>${api.common.login.oauth.token}</beans:value></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1"><beans:value>${user.login.username.param}</beans:value></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2"><beans:value>${user.login.password.param}</beans:value></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="3" ref="authenticationManager"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="4" ref="tokenServices"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="5" ref="clientDetails"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="6"><beans:value>${api.common.login.oauth.grant_type.two_factor}</beans:value></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="7" ref="userAccountServiceImpl"></beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customPasswordGrant" class="com.xxxx.api.grants.CustomPasswordGrant">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="authenticationManager"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="tokenServices"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="clientDetails"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="3" ref="userAccountServiceImpl"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="4"><beans:value>${api.common.login.oauth.grant_type.custom_password}</beans:value></beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<!-- End Of Custom Grant Types -->

<beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="api" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="clientServiceImpl" class="com.xxxx.api.services.ClientServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use the same `AuthenticationManager` for clients and users, but that only makes life difficult, especially if you use a `ProviderManager` (like you are), because the client and user credentials are presented in the same form (`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`). It's far easier if you stick to the provided default behaviour which is a separate `AuthenticationManager` for clients that is created for you by the framework. All the samples and integration tests use this dual authentication manager pattern, so there is plenty to crib from.

Comment: OK, I've been here before and tried what you said with little success (getting errors). I modified my previous post with the entire security-context.xml. Also, note both custom grant types are returning a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. Thanks

Comment: You just have to create *separate* `AuthenticationManagers` for each use case (you appear to now have 3 - clients, and 2 custom grants). I can't see where you secure the /token endpoint, but that's the one with the client details (get rid of your `CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider` and use the regular `ClientDetailsAuthenticationManager`). The other two are there and you are injecting the same `AuthenticationManager` into both.